# Understanding the filter service from the API docs

Tags: angularjs

The Angular [API reference docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$filter) uses braces `[]` when defining the `$filter` service.  What do the braces mean in this context?

`{{ expression [| filter_name[:parameter_value] ... ] }}`

I *think* it means optional.  However, I've seen code written like this:

```
        <select ng-model="query.level" class="input-medium">
            <option selected value="">All</option>
            <option selected value="introductory">Introductory</option>
            <option selected value="intermediate">Intermediate</option>
            <option selected value="advanced">Advanced</option>
        </select>

        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="session in event.sessions | orderBy:sortorder | limitTo:2 | filter:query">
                ...
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And a controller like

```
        $scope.event = {
            sessions: [
            {
                name: 'Blah',
                level: 'Advanced'
            },
            {
                name: 'another thing',
                level: 'Intermediate'
            }
            ]
        }
```

`query` is not a custom or [pre-built filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter).  I fail to see the connection between `filter:query` and the documentation.  Is filter an expression that includes a magic variable somehow initialized simply by it's use in `ng-model`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion is that `filter` used in this context does not mean "Angular filter" it actually means filter the list. It's the "filter" filter. The part after the colon in this case is not the name of a filter, but the argument to the "filter" filter.

`orderBy` is a filter.

`limitTo` is a filter.

`filter` is also a filter.

You do not write `filter:orderBy` or `filter:limitTo`, you just write `orderBy` or `limitTo`. So in the this case, they are writing `filter`, not `filter:filter`.

To put it another way, `query` IS NOT A FILTER. `query` is the argument to the `filter` filter, which is included in the list of built-in filters: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter

I think that was just bad naming on Angular's part.

Comment: Another piece of the magic is the fact we setup two way binding by way of adding `ng-model` to the `select` element.